# Bien vs buen/bueno/buena to describe something good

Tags: selección-de-palabras, gramática, adjetivos

I have encountered phrases like these:

> La buena comida.
>
> El buen hombre.
>
> Buenos días.

However in none of these instances is it grammatically correct to substitute *bien* even though it also means good and it is also an adjective (at least as I understand it).

When and how do I use *bien* as opposed to *buen/bueno/buena* to describe something good?

Comment: "bien" is not an adjective, but a noun.

Comment: It can be, but more often it's an adverb.  It's the same difference we have in English between good/well except that we're pretty bad about it in English :D

Comment: @JuanCespedes: *bien* is almost never a noun, in common usage. It's almost always an adverb. See [here](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=bien). It's a noun when it's used like the English word "goods", but that's not a common usage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference is quite simple: *bien* is an adverb, while *bueno/a* is an adjective.

You should use *bien* when it stands alone (*esto está bien*), when it modifies verbs, specially the participle (*esto está bien escrito*) or as an intensifier, more or less equivalent with *muy* (*lo tenemos bien difícil*, equivalent to *lo tenemos muy difícil*).

You should use *bueno/a* when it modifies a noun (*era un hombre bueno*); if it goes before the noun in masculine singular, *bueno* becomes *buen* (*era un buen hombre*).

After the verb *estar*, both words are usable, but with different meanings. Unfortunately, the meaning can change between countries. *Está bueno* in Spain usually means *it tastes good*, while in some American countries means *it is good*. *Está bien* in Spain means *it is well done* or *he feels good*, but in some American countries this meaning may change.

Answer (score 3):

While `bien` can also describe nouns like adjectives do, it's use implies the epitome of good in whatever genre of context it is in.

```
¡Que bueno! vs ¡Qué bien!
```

Think of the difference between That's good and F**k yeah, or This place is so great/perfect for us!
Bien is so stupendous that it affects both parties

Sometimes you can hear it being used in place of **`very`** or even **`very well`**

- Bien hecho
- Estoy bien trabajado
- ¡Escúchenme bien para sobrevivir!
  -

It can even also be used to describe 'bad'.

```
Está bien malo eso.
```

Imagine seeing a scene similiar to those in the Final Destination franchise, those can be described as Very BAD, or rather....  This is horrible!

http://dle.rae.es/bien